# MVC LinQ search error

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3

im very new to MVC3, and im tasked with adding a search box to my MVC3 controller, and making the controller display results based on a search from the database.

My code pasted below, throws up an error, the error message is pasted also.

```
public ViewResult Index(string searchString)
    {
        var newsItem = from n in db.NewsItems
                       select n;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            newsItem = newsItem.Where(n => n.Posted.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
                       || n.Posted.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));

        }


        return View(db.NewsItems.ToList());
    }
```

Error:

> 'System.DateTime' does not contain a definition for 'ToUpper' and no
>   extension method 'ToUpper' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.DateTime' could be found (are you missing a using directive or
>   an assembly reference?)
>   C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My
>   Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\Web_Assignment\Web_Assignment\Controllers\NewsController.cs 27  40  Web_Assignment

Comment: Is this homework? Your error is fairly descriptive.

Answer (score 2):

I think that property Posted has DateTyme type. Then if you really want to search in DateTime column - you need to convert it to string type: `newsItem.Where(n => n.Posted.ToString().ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())`
But maybe you really want to search in Text property?

```
newsItem.Where(n => n.Text.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
```